# Why can I redefine a const in a smaller scope?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, scope, constants, accelerated-c++

I'm working my way through Accelerated C++ right now, and I've encountered a fundamental lack of understanding regarding scope and code blocks on my part.

There is an exercise at the end of chapter 1 that wants you to decide whether this code is will run:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    {
        const std::string s = "a string";
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
        {
            const std::string s = "another string";
            std::cout << s << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I was sure it wouldn't, but it does. My hobby programming experience was that variables declared in a block are available to other blocks contained within it, but not those outside of it.

And that must be at least half-true, since removing the second declaration of s will output "a string" twice, giving me the impression that s as declared in the second block is also present in the third block.

I also tried removing the braces of the third block entirely, resulting in the compilation error I expected in the first place. But how is that different from declaring a constant that already exists in the scope of the third block? Does the declaration of a constant only carry over to a smaller scope if there is no second declaration in that smaller scope?

I've gone through everything in the book up until this point again to see if I missed something, but I can't find any information on how variable and const declarations are affected by curly braces.

Comment: Try adding another `std::cout << s << std::endl;` between the first two `}`

Comment: The second `s` is a new variable which shadows one from outer scope. It can as well have a different type.

Comment: The key word to look for is: _shadowing_. `s` in the nested scope shadows the one in the upper scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't just apply to constants though, that doesn't matter.

> But how is that different from declaring a constant that already exists in the scope of the third block?

You are introducing another scope, where the variable `s` has not been defined, so it is perfectly legal to define one. If you remove one, you'll get a redefinition error, because you already have an `s` in the same scope.

> Does the declaration of a constant only carry over to a smaller scope if there is no second declaration in that smaller scope?

Not really. Your second `s` is *shadowing* the first one. Technically, both of them exist, but you have no way of accessing the first one. Sometimes you do, with the help of the scope resolution operator, but in your case, no.

```
// global scope
int a;
void f() {
    int a = 0;
    a = 4; // local 'a'.
    ::a = 4; // global 'a'.
}
```

> I can't find any information on how variable and const declarations are affected by curly braces.

Curly braces in general introduce a new scope (although there are some exceptions). As long as a variable with a given name is not defined in the current scope, you can define it. It doesn't matter if there is a variable with the same name in a scope outside of  it, but your compiler will likely warn you about it.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Kind of weird that the book expects you to know this this though. Just checked the index, "shadow" or "shadowing" isn't mentioned once in the entire book. It also doesn't really make sense thematically since this is supposed to check your knowledge of constants. Maybe it's a typo and `s = "another string"` was meant to be in the third block.

Comment: FYI If you want to explicitly avoid shadowing try `-Wshadow` option of g++

Answer (score 3):

Java and C++ are one of the few that allows this.
C# does not allow this.
It is called Variable Shadowing. If you declare a variable with same name in a smaller inner block as outer blocks variable then you get name masking.
So it doesnt matter that you have a const variable because the inner variable is a different variable altogether.